# Individual apperance for each ttk.Notebook tab?

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, appearance

Is it possible to have individual apperance for each ttk.Notebook tab? Currently by creating my own theme using `theme_create` I was able to achieve this [image: result]

Active tab is white with black text. Other tabs are black with white text on it.
What I would like to achieve is **different color for each when selected**.
For instance: Tab1 with red color, Tab2 with blue, etc.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab_control.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create('tab_bar_theme', parent='classic', settings={'TNotebook': {'configure': {'background': '#888888'}},
                                                                'TNotebook.Tab': {'configure': {'background': '#555555',
                                                                                                'foreground': 'white',
                                                                                                'padding': [10, 10]},
                                                                                  'label': {'side': ''},
                                                                                  'map': {'background': [
                                                                                      ('selected', '#ffffff')],
                                                                                      'foreground': [
                                                                                          ('selected', 'black')]}}})
style.theme_use('tab_bar_theme')

for i in range(6):
    tab_control.add(Frame(), text='Tab' + str(i))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you include your code? And what you tried so far?

Comment: It's added now. What I tried is basically included in the code. I tried to create new "Notebook.Tab" element for theme, but it's been always changing all the tabs appearance.